# How to create table of counts for categorical property keys?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two snippets of code that each produce a table with team name and the number of wins respective number of losses for each team (for football results).

```
MATCH (t:Team)-[r]-(m:Match)
WHERE r.result = 'WIN'
WITH t, t.name AS team_name, COUNT(r.result) AS num_wins
RETURN team_name, num_wins;

MATCH (t:Team)-[r]-(m:Match)
WHERE r.result = 'LOSE'
WITH t, t.name AS team_name, COUNT(r.result) AS num_lose
RETURN team_name, num_lose;
```

The relationship has two alternatives :HOME_TEAM and :AWAY_TEAM. For this particular data set there are no ties.

I would like the above results to instead be on one single table with the three headers "team_name", "num_wins" and "num_lose". How do I do this? Everything I have attempted so far has failed.

Comment: Is there a specific relationship type between :Team and :Match that we can use here? If so there's a shortcut we can use for this kind of query.

Comment: @InverseFalcon Sorry, I should have included that information. I have now updated the question. I have accepted cypersams answer as it worked perfectly but if you have another method I would love to see it. Eager to learn!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there are relationships between `Team`s and `Match`s that either do not have a `result` or have some other result value (like `TIE`), this query first filters for `WIN` or `LOSE` results, and then simply uses the [aggregating function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) `COUNT` to count the wins and losses for each team.

```
MATCH (t:Team)-[r]-(:Match)
WHERE r.result IN ['WIN', 'LOSE']
RETURN t.name AS team_name, r.result AS result, COUNT(*) AS cnt;
```

(This query also assumes that teams have unique names.)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach you can use is to count the relationships that had a "WIN" result and subtract that from the total relationships (which can be obtained by counting relationship degrees). This only works if "WIN" and "LOSE" are the only possible results, and if there is always a result:

```
MATCH (t:Team)-[r:HOME_TEAM|AWAY_TEAM]-()
WHERE r.result = 'WIN'
WITH t, count(r) as wins
RETURN t.name as team_name, wins, size((t)-[:HOME_TEAM|AWAY_TEAM]-()) - wins as losses
```